# Does modifying the same entity in Entity Framework will save the entity to the database synchronously? throw exception?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm investigating a bug in our systems and when reviewing the code I saw that the developer queried twice the same entity and saved it with different values.

I simplified the case for example:

```
Person Data:
id  |   name    |   age |   HasLicence
1   |   david   |   27  |   true


using (DbContext dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    Person person1 = dbContext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.age == 27);
    Person person2 = dbContext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.name == "david");
    
    person1.HasLicence = false;
    person2.HasLicence = true;
    .
    .
    // more logic..
    .
    .
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Does this will save the entity to the database synchronously? throw exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is both variables are referencing same object instance(proxy).

So when you update person1.HasLicence same value will be on person2.HasLicence.

```
a.HasLicence = true;
Assert.AreEqual(a.HasLicence , b.HasLicence );

b.HasLicence = false;
Assert.AreEqual(a.HasLicence , b.HasLicence );

_dataContext.Save(); // updates only one entity
```

Behavior might be different if you have some changed settings for datacontext.

IF you want to know more how entity frameworks works you can access it on github

> https://github.com/dotnet/ef6

Comment: Thanks. The last value will be set indeed. Unfortunately I couldn't find any helpful information on the link. What datacontext setting could affect that behavior?